# Почему вылетает программа если значение setTickCount сделать переменной типа int?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня шкала должна соответствовать определенному шагу либо 5 либо 10 если максимальное значение больше 10 . Когда считаю шаг я объявляю переменную `int Step;` По чему, если я выполняю подсчёт шага таким образом :

```
if (yMax>0 && yMax<=10)
{ Step = (int) (yMax*10 + 1); }
else if (yMax>10 && yMax<=50)
{ Step = (int) (yMax/5 + 1); }
else if (yMax>50 && yMax<=1000)
{ Step = (int) (yMax/10 + 1); }
else if (yMax>1000 && yMax<=10000)
{ Step = (int) (yMax/100 + 1); }
else {
  Step = 51;
}
```

и передаю этот параметр в `axisY->setTickCount(Step);` Программа вылетает с ошибкой `runtime error` Это не совпадение типов , слишком большой параметр или что то другое ?
Весь код вывода графиков:

```
#include "chart.h"
#include <QPointF>
#include <QList>

#include <QtCharts>
#include <QtCharts/QChartView>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QSplineSeries>
#include <QtCharts/QValueAxis>
#include <QtCharts/QCategoryAxis>

Chart::Chart(QStringList PlotName,
             double xMin,
             double xMax,
             double yMin,
             double yMax,
             std::vector<QList<QPointF> *> &ListPoint,
             QStringList DiagramName)
{
    //![1]
    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->setTitle(PlotName[0]);
    if (DiagramName[0]=="") {
        chart->legend()->setVisible(false);
    }
    //![1]

    //![2]
    QValueAxis *axisX = new QValueAxis;
    axisX->setTitleText(PlotName[1]);
    axisX->setTitleBrush(Qt::black); // Цвет названия
    axisX->setLabelsColor(Qt::black); // Цвет элементов оси
    chart->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignBottom);
    axisX->setTickCount(21);
    axisX->setRange(int(xMin+(xMin<0.0?-0.5:+0.5)), int(xMax+(xMax<0.0?-0.5:+0.5)));
    //![2]

    if (yMin>=0 && yMin<=1) { yMin=0; }
    if (yMax>=1 || yMin<=-1) {
        yMin = int(yMin + 1 + (yMin<0.0?-0.5:+0.5));
        yMax = int(yMax + 1 + (yMax<0.0?-0.5:+0.5));

    } else if ((yMax>0 && yMax<=1) || (yMin<0 && yMin>=-1)) {
        yMax = 1; yMin = -1;
    }
    if (yMin>10 || yMin< -10 ) { yMin = (int) ((9 * (yMin / abs(yMin)) + yMin) / 10) * 10; }
    if (yMax>10 || yMax< -10 ) { yMax = (int) ((9 * (yMax / abs(yMax)) + yMax) / 10) * 10; }
    if (yMax>0 && yMax<=10)
    { Step = (int) (yMax*10 + 1); }
    else if (yMax>10 && yMax<=50)
    { Step = (int) (yMax/5 + 1); }
    else if (yMax>50 && yMax<=1000)
    { Step = (int) (yMax/10 + 1); }
    else if (yMax>1000 && yMax<=10000)
    { Step = (int) (yMax/100 + 1); }
    else {
      Step = 51;
    }
    //![3]
    QValueAxis *axisY = new QValueAxis;
    axisY->setTitleText(PlotName[2]);
    chart->addAxis(axisY, Qt::AlignLeft);
    axisY->setTitleBrush(Qt::black); // Цвет названия
    axisY->setLabelsColor(Qt::black); // Цвет элементов оси
    axisY->setTickCount(Step);
    axisY->setRange(yMin, yMax);
    //![3]

    // Customize plot area background
    QLinearGradient plotAreaGradient;;
    plotAreaGradient.setStart(QPointF(0, 1));
    plotAreaGradient.setFinalStop(QPointF(1, 0));
    plotAreaGradient.setColorAt(0.0, QRgb(0xd2d0d1));
    plotAreaGradient.setColorAt(1.0, QRgb(0x4c4547));
    plotAreaGradient.setCoordinateMode(QGradient::ObjectBoundingMode);
    chart->setPlotAreaBackgroundBrush(plotAreaGradient);
    chart->setPlotAreaBackgroundVisible(true);

    //![4]
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<ListPoint.size();++i) {
        QLineSeries *diagrama = new QLineSeries;      
        if (DiagramName[i]!="") {
            diagrama->setName(DiagramName[i]);
        }

        diagrama->append(*ListPoint[i]);
        chart->addSeries(diagrama);
        diagrama->attachAxis(axisX);
        diagrama->attachAxis(axisY);
    }
    //![4]

    //![5]
    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    //![5]

    //![6]
    QMainWindow* window = new QMainWindow();
    window->setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window->setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, false);
    window->resize(960, 540);
    window->show();
    //![6]
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите (хотя бы в отладчике), чему равен `Step` перед вызовом `axisY->setTickCount(Step);`. Чему он будет равен, если yMax внезапно окажется ==0 или >10000?  И еще, кажется странным первое условие в `else if ((0>yMax && yMax<=1) || (0>yMin && yMin>=-1))` - если уж `yMax <0`, то оно по-любому будет и меньше 1. Опечатка?

Comment: @Vladimir В отладчике Step=35, не в этом проблема. ((0>yMax && yMax<=1) || (0>yMin && yMin>=-1))  да опечатка/ хотя else стоит добавить

Comment: @Vladimir ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file C:\Qt\5.10.0\mingw53_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 549